# XML Element Overriding

Tags: xml, xsd

I have not come up with a good, clean way to do this, so I will bring my woes to you!

I want to represent a configuration in XML. I have a number of fields, some required, some not, most with strict constraints. I have a base configuration which I will represent as config.xml which might have some contents like this:

```
...
<config>
  <element-a value="3.2" />
  <element-b value="hello world" />
</config>
...
```

There's a schema associated that says both of those fields are required. One is a float and one is a string. Now I have another configuration which is similar to the first with one minor change. I would like to represent it like this:

```
...
<include base-config="config.xml">
<config>
  <element-a value="1.5" />
</config>
...
```

In effect, this new configuration pulls all the elements from the base configuration file and only specifies what it's overriding. I can't use the same schema for this because now all the elements are optional, but I want to maintain the same constraints on the data (preferably without having to create a new schema with the same elements all made "optional").

Is there an XML-compliant way to do this? Or has anyone accomplished this with any luck? Maybe you have a design pattern you'd like to share?

Currently, I'm anticipating having two copies of every schema and in the processing step I will load the base then overload the updated elements. This is a cumbersome method, so hopefully there's something better.

Answer (score 0):

If you modularize your schema such that you define the restrictions using global types, then you can re use those types when you define your base config schema (where every element/most elements are required) and the optional config schema (where every element is optional). This approach would probably also work using global elements and then referring to them in the sequences.

However, xml schema cannot help you with reading the actual configuration files and performing the overloading stuff.

Comment: Say I have GlobalTypes included by BaseSchema and OverrideableSchema. How would I pick and choose elements to be required in BaseSchema and blanket optional in OverrideableSchema?

Comment: (As for reading the actual configuration and performing the overloading, I completely expected XML to NOT help me here. My solution in implementing would be to always require a base include that passed the stricter schema.)